# SwiftUI populate data on ScrollView by call function

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am just start learning swift and swiftUI, hope somebody can help to resolve my problem I created a `CollectionView` that show data stored in `categories` inside `CollectionView` struct, and now I have created a `readCategories` function in `Function` class with some other mock up data, I just don't know how to update the `CollectionView` to run `readCategories` and populate the Category A, B, C, D instead?

Thanks in advance.

```
struct CategoryModel: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var title: String
    init(title: String) {
        id = UUID()
        self.title = title
       }
}

class Data {
    static var categoryModels =  [CategoryModel]()
}

class Functions {
    static func readCategories(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
     
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            if Data.categoryModels.count == 0 {
                Data.categoryModels.append(CategoryModel(title: "Category A"))
                Data.categoryModels.append(CategoryModel(title: "Category B"))
                Data.categoryModels.append(CategoryModel(title: "Category C"))
                Data.categoryModels.append(CategoryModel(title: "Category D"))
            }
        }
    
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion()
        }
    }
}

struct CollectionView: View {

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    var categories: [CategoryModel] = [
        CategoryModel(title: "Category 1"),
        CategoryModel(title: "Category 2"),
        CategoryModel(title: "Category 3"),
        CategoryModel(title: "Category 4")
    ]
    var body: some View {
     
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
            LazyVStack(spacing: 130) {
                ForEach(categories) { category in
                    Text(category.title)
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The SwiftUI *philosophy* is a bit different from traditional UIKit.

The recommended way is to put the data model into a class conforming to `ObservableObject` (by the way please never name a custom struct or class `Data`, this can cause unexpected behavior). The benefit is the UI is updated automatically when the model is being modified.

For example this is the data model, it populates the data source with the 4 categories and provides a function to add a new category

```
class DataModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var categories : [CategoryModel]
    
    init() {
        categories = [CategoryModel(title: "Category A"),
                      CategoryModel(title: "Category B"),
                      CategoryModel(title: "Category C"),
                      CategoryModel(title: "Category D")]
    }
    
    func addCategory() {
        categories.append(CategoryModel(title: "New Category"))
    }
}
```

In the view the `@StateObject` is the *receiver*. Whenever `categories` in `DataModel` changes the `body` of the view is called.

```
struct CollectionView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var dataModel = DataModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                dataModel.addCategory()
            }, label: {
                Label(
                    title: { Text("Add Category") },
                    icon: { Image(systemName: "plus") }
                )
            })
            Divider()
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
                LazyVStack(spacing: 130) {
                    ForEach(dataModel.categories) { category in
                        Text(category.title)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```